# Codigos-fonte em Projetos

Tags: c, c++, netbeans

Se eu tenho 10 projetos no NetBeans, esses 10 projetos irão utilizar um sistema de gravação de Logs, esse sistema contem um Log.h e um Log.c. Como todos os projetos irão ter que usar esses dois arquivos de log para gerar logs, precisarei copiar para cada projeto os dois arquivos. Mas isso causa um problema, por exemplo: se irei alterar o Log.c terei que alterar em todos os projetos. Nesse caso, há alguma forma de incluir esses dois arquivos em todos os projetos sem ter que copiar os dois arquivos para cada projeto?

Comment: Uma ideia é fazer uma library/biblioteca com o Log.c e incluir o Log.h nos ficheiros que usam as funções do Log.c. Depois é preciso incluir a biblioteca nos 10 projectos. Não meto isto como resposta em baixo porque não sei ao certo como fazer isto no NetBeans. Deve também dar para adicionar o mesmo Log.c aos 10 projectos, e ficar com um único ficheiro Log.c para todos.

Comment: Por que as tags [tag:c#] e [tag:java] fazem parte desta pergunta?

Comment: Um erro, ja corrigi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não posso comentar e como não sei qual o compilador que está utilizando vou colocar aqui uma resposta geral.

Você terá de criar uma biblioteca estática. Vamos supor que se chama `liblog.a` no seu compilador terá de adicionar a flag `-llog`, ou seja, `-l` substitui o lib( tem de ter sempre lib no nome! ).

Para além disso tem de ter um header file contendo os protótipos da suas funções para poder invocá-las no seu programa, neste caso o Log.h.

Para lhe facilitar a vida pode colocar a biblioteca estática no LIBRARY_PATH default do seu compilador e o seu header file `Log.h` no INCLUDE_PATH default do seu compilador, costumam ser respetivamente  `lib`e `include` o nome desses diretorios.

Ou se quiser pode criar os seus próprios directórios para colocar as suas bibliotecas e headers, mas terá de indicar sempre a sua localização ao compilador.

Comment: Essa liblog.a, deve ter apenas a implementação dos prototipos definidos no Log.h?

Comment: Pode ter mais, mas normlmente pode ter outras funções que são utilizadas pelos protótipos definidos, ou até variáveis.

Comment: Entendi, o que eu queria saber agora, é se o uso de bibliotecas estáticas é conveniente para desenvolver sistemas?

Comment: Que tipo de sistemas? Operativos?

Comment: Sistemas comerciais, como ERP etc

Comment: Penso que sim, não tenho a certeza :/

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma pasta com os arquivos que deseja compartilhar entre os diversos projetos. Depois abra o projeto desejado e clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o projeto e selecione `Adicionar Item Existente da Pastas...` adicione as pastas desejadas e clique em adicionar. As pastas serão indexadas ao projeto.

Para incluir em outros projetos basta repetir os passos nos projetos que desejar. Surgeri fazer isso com pastas pelo fato de ser mais fácil para a organização, o mesmo pode ser feito por arquivos, a única diferença é que terá que selecionar a opção `Adicionar Item Existente...`.

Após adicionar os arquivos ou pasta nos projetos desejados basta alterar os arquivos em comum uma vez que todos projetos terão acesso a alteração. Usei essa funcionalidade do netbeans apenas em Java e C mas creio que há suporte para todas linguagens de programação.

Comment: É um bom jeito, mas também depende, alguns projetos podem precisar somente de alguns arquivos dessa pasta, e você acaba incluindo coisas desnecessárias ao projeto.

Comment: @Vynstus leia o segundo parágrafo novamente, o seu ponto é levantado ali.